# Android Compose: How to draw a shadow only left and right of a Box?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, how would I implement a box with rounded corners that has a shadow only on the left and right side. The top and bottom edge should not have a shadow. Also the box should not have any borders.

This is the desired result:
[image: UI Button sample]

One idea would be to place the content between 2 Boxes. One with only left shadow and the other one with only right shadow. But also in this way I am not sure how to completely cut-off the shadow on top and bottom.

Comment: In your example the shadow on the left and right extend to the top and bottom of the button respectively for more than 30 pixels. This seems to be in conflict with "*how to completely cut-off the shadow on top and bottom*". What shoud it be?

Comment: It should be as close to the reference picture as possible. It's difficult to describe the detailed requirement in words. Thiis is why I added the picture as reference what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this and see how it will works for you, but honesty i don't see any advantage of using it instead of simple `Button` because of shadows.

It's basically `Row` with two `Spacer` behind it. Spacers are providing the shadow, shadow is defined mostly by spacer's `width` and `height`. There is also bottom padding on spacer because i noticed that shadow under button is bigger that the shadow on the top.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ClippedShadowButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    @DrawableRes iconRes: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {

    //Outline paddings to make space for shadows
    val outlineHorizontalPadding = 20.dp
    val outlineVerticalPadding = 20.dp

    //Inner padding of button
    val innerVerticalPadding = 16.dp
    val innerHorizontalPadding = 24.dp

    //Spacer width will determine shadow width
    val spacerWidth = 24.dp
    //Extra height to make shadows bigger than the button
    val spacerExtraHeight = 4.dp
    val shadowElevation = 16.dp

    //Shadow offset from outlineHorizontalPadding
    val shadowOffsetX = 6.dp

    val buttonShape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp)
    val shadowColor = Color(0xFF707070)
    val ambientColor = Color(0xFFFEFEFE)
    val contentColor = Color(0xFF8391A8)


    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var spacerHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 0.dp) }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
    ) {

        //Left shadow
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    start = outlineHorizontalPadding - (spacerWidth / 2f) + shadowOffsetX,
                    bottom = shadowElevation
                )
                .size(width = spacerWidth, height = spacerHeight + spacerExtraHeight)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterStart)
                .shadow(
                    elevation = shadowElevation,
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    ambientColor = ambientColor,
                    spotColor = shadowColor,
                    clip = true
                )
        )

        //Right shadow
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    end = outlineHorizontalPadding - (spacerWidth / 2f) + shadowOffsetX,
                    bottom = shadowElevation
                )
                .size(width = spacerWidth, height = spacerHeight + spacerExtraHeight)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd)
                .shadow(
                    elevation = shadowElevation,
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    ambientColor = ambientColor,
                    spotColor = shadowColor
                )
        )

        //Button
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(alignment = Alignment.Center)
                .padding(horizontal = outlineHorizontalPadding, vertical = outlineVerticalPadding)
                .background(color = Color.White, shape = buttonShape)
                .clip(shape = buttonShape)
                .clickable(onClick = onClick)
                .padding(horizontal = innerHorizontalPadding, vertical = innerVerticalPadding)
                .onSizeChanged {
                    spacerHeight = with(density) { it.height.toDp() + (innerVerticalPadding * 2) }
                }
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = iconRes),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = contentColor
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(width = 8.dp))
            Text(text = text, color = contentColor)
        }
    }
}
```

With this i was able to make this result. You can try modify the values to change the shadow.

[image]

Comment: cool, this looks already very good. thx for your effort!